# Add additional column to CSV when converting from excel to csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to translate an excel workbook with multiple sheets to multiple CSVs. 
During this conversion, I would also like to add an additional column at the front as rundate. It is working, but the additional column is giving me grief. 
Any tips would be helpful.

```
def translate_xlsx_to_csv(files):
    file = files[0]
    print(file)
    obj = s3.meta.client.get_object(Bucket= BUCKET_NAME, Key= file)
    data = obj['Body'].read()
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data) , sheet_name=None)
    try:
        if len(data_xls.keys())==5:
            for key, value in data_xls.items():
                filename = f"/tmp/{key}.csv"
                data_xls[key].to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
                df = pd.read_csv(filename)
                run_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                df.insert(0, "run_date", run_date)
                df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        raise (e)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is giving you grief? The `df.insert(0, 'run_date', run_date)` call works when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could attempt something like this:

```py
def translate_xlsx_to_csv(files):
    file = files[0]
    print(file)
    obj = s3.meta.client.get_object(Bucket= BUCKET_NAME, Key= file)
    data = obj['Body'].read()
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data) , sheet_name=None)
    try:
        if len(data_xls.keys())==5:
            for key, value in data_xls.items():
                filename = f"/tmp/{key}.csv"
                data_xls[key].to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
                df = pd.read_csv(filename)
                run_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

                ## Changing this:
                df["run_date"] = run_date
                ##

                df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        raise (e)
```

That should create the additional column that you are looking for.